# I keep getting an attribute error 'int' object has no attribute 'dollars'

Tags: python, class, attributes

Im working on this Money class and everything worked fine up until the multiplication. I keep getting an attribute error and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. The multiplication is of type float.

```
class Money:
    def __init__(self, d, c):
        self.dollars = d
        self.cents = c

    def __str__(self):
        return '${}.{:02d}'.format(self.dollars, self.cents)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Money({},{})'.format(repr(self.dollars), self.cents)

    def add(self, other):
        d = self.dollars + other.dollars
        c = self.cents + other.cents
        while c > 99:
            d += 1
            c -= 100
        return Money(d,c)

    def subtract(self, other):
        d = self.dollars - other.dollars
        c = self.cents - other.cents
        while c < 0:
            d -= 1
            c += 100
        return Money(d,c)

    def times(self, mult):
        d = self.dollars * mult.dollars
        c = self.cents * mult.cents
        while c > 99:
            d *= 1
            c *= 100
        return Money(d,c)


>>> m2 = Money(10,10)
>>> m2.times(3)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module> m2.times(3) 
  File "/Users/kylerbolden/Desktop/hw2.py", line 67, in times
    d = float(self.dollars) * float(mult.dollars)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dollars'
```

Comment: please modify your code block. the first line of your code seems to have been chopped off from the rest!

Comment: Please, Please, **PLEASE**, post the exact error you're getting. Or at least show how you're using the functions you provided. Without that, it would be a guessing game trying to figure which function is raising an error.

Comment: >>> m2 = Money(10,10)
>>> m2.times(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    m2.times(3)
  File "/Users/kylerbolden/Desktop/hw2.py", line 67, in times
    d = float(self.dollars) * float(mult.dollars)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dollars'

Comment: Thanks for showing the error Kyler, but could you post it in the question instead and format it like you did your code? It a little hard to read in the comments.

Comment: `times(3)`. `3` is not a money object hence your error. Assume you meant `d = self.dollars * mult` in your `times` function. BTW: if you name it `times` as `__mul__` then you can do: m2 * 3.

Comment: It seems that your `mult` parameter is being passed in as a integer. And of course, integers have no attribute `.dollars`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `m2.times(3)`, you're passing the `int` `3` to the `times` method. In the times method, though, you're trying to multiply by `mult.dollars`, and not the `dollars` (`3`) that you actually passed.

`mult.dollars` doesn't work like `self.dollars` would. In fact, it's not a valid construct at all.

Try

```
>>> class Money:
...     def __init__(self, d, c):
...         self.dollars = d
...         self.cents = c
...     def times(self, mult):
...         d = self.dollars * mult
...         c = self.cents * mult
...         while c > 99:
...             d *= 1
...             c *= 100
...         return Money(d, c)
```

You'll obviously have to modify the rest of your code, as well.

It seems you want to return a new `Money` object instead of a balance with each of these methods, but to demonstrate the point I made above:

```
>>> class Money:
...     def __init__(self, d, c):
...         self.dollars = d
...         self.cents = c
...     def times(self, mult):
...         d = self.dollars * mult
...         c = self.cents * mult
...         while c > 99:
...             d *= 1
...             c *= 100
...         return (d,c)
... 
>>> m2 = Money(10, 10)
>>> m2.times(3)
(30, 30)
```

Edit: Okay, the above doesn't seem to be what you're looking for, but I'll leave it for people running into a similar error. What you need to fix in your code is the `mult` object that you're trying to pass. Your `add` and `subtract` methods all have the same parameters: `self` and `other`, where `other` is another instance of the `Money` class, I presume. So, you're trying to multiply, add, or subtract different balances, basically? In that case, change the `mult.dollars` and `mult.cents` to `other.dollars` and `other.cents` so that you can access those attributes for another `Money` object.

After changing that:

```
>>> class Money:
...     def __init__(self, d, c):
...         self.dollars = d
...         self.cents = c
...     def times(self, other):
...         d = self.dollars * other.dollars
...         c = self.cents * other.cents
...         while c > 99:
...             d *= 1
...             c *= 100
...         return Money(d,c)
... 
>>> m2 = Money(2, 3)
>>> m3 = Money(4, 5)
>>> m2.times(m3)
Money(8,15)
```

Also, you might want to look into the `d *= 1` and `c *= 100` lines, but that should answer your initial question.

Comment: Im not having an issue with the other functions, only the multiplication function. and when i try your method it says that dollars is not defined.

Comment: How have the other functions worked? In your add function, for example, the `other` parameter in your argument is being passed as an `int` type, I'm assuming, and you're calling `other.dollars` in the function definition. It doesn't have an attribute "dollars". Does that make sense?

Comment: I think i may have gotten it. i removed the dollars and cents from mult.dollars and i got it to do the multiplication.

Comment: I see what you're doing with the `other` parameter. See above.

Comment: This is exactly what I did with the exception of the while statement. Thank you very much.

Comment: Should be... While c>99:     d+=1 c-=100